# Should I hide the android actionbar or try to style it

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am building an app for Android and iOS. It is working but the creative people want to totally change the style so that the top part of the screen (where the actionbar is on android) is taller and has their logo centered in it.
Should I hide the actionbar and put the logo (and custom nav icons) at the top of my layouts, OR should I try to change the style of the actionbar (make it taller and include the logo in the center)? Either option seems a bit painful, but I don't think I can talk them out of it.

Comment: hide it and create your own xml layout and use as header to your activity..as actionbar...after all the toolbar in api 21 is a viewgroup..

Comment: Fire the creative people and hire replacements that actually want their app to look like it belongs on the device.

Comment: :) good advice, but the CEO is the driving force.

Answer (score 0):

you should create own View. You can't center any item (icon, logo, title) in ActionBar, also you can't change height. Android ACtionBar's guidelines are very strict. You might change some params by using "findViewById" and passing hardcoded android ids, but they might change for different device manufacturers resulting no change on these units (or even some crashes)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would probably modify the ActionBar and try to maintain as much of the functionality as possible.  Especially if this is a long running project and it might go back to the standard action bar later.

You can do this by adding your own custom view that will contain your centered logo to the action bar:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_view);
```

You can then use the action buttons and home/up buttons as you normally would.

Depending on your needs however, you may find it challenging to keep the logo centered since the home and action buttons will add to the left and right respectively which will shift the center view if unbalanced.  If so, you can still use your custom action bar view from above and add buttons directly to it inside a FrameLayout to maintain the centering.

To change the height, you can use themes and styles.  Wherever you define your styles, set the `actionBarStyle` and the height in that style:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle">
    <item name="android:height">70dp</item>
</style>
```